# Disabling login button in openerp

Tags: javascript, odoo

How to disable login button in openerp?
I want to disable the login button in openerp login page. Can anyone please help me out on how to disable a button in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disable login  button and or hide login button using js

self.$el.find('button').hide();
in the start function of instance.web.Login